# Can't register JWT authentication strategy in loopback 4

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, loopback4

I'm using IBM loopback 4 and trying to secure some APIs using JWT, I've created all the required authentication components (**sequence, strategy , component**) in order to use the annotation @authenticate, but the application can't find the strategy "jwt" even though I registered it in application.ts

1. **Strategy registration in application file**
      this.add(createBindingFromClass(// my jwtstrategyclass))
2. Getting the error : **The strategy 'jwt' is not available.** / **AUTHENTICATION_STRATEGY_NOT_FOUND**

Answer (score 3):

LoopBack 4 provides a simple way to register custom authentication strategies using `registerAuthenticationStrategy()`:

```
// application.ts

import {registerAuthenticationStrategy} from '@loopback/authentication';

export class MyApplication extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
) {
  constructor(options?: ApplicationConfig) {
    super(options);

    //...

    registerAuthenticationStrategy(this, YourAuthenticationStrategy);

    //...
  }
}
```

Replace `YourAuthenticationStrategy` with your authentication strategy class.

Further reading:

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Loopback-component-authentication.html#registering-a-custom-authentication-strategy

Comment: Thanks @Rifa, it works but for this "registerAuthenticationStrategy" strategy registration to work the loopback context has to be the latest one, therefore running npm install --save @loopback/context is required, otherwise it won't work, thanks once again .

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amine ! While using `registerAuthenticationStrategy`, I was getting error: `Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Context'`. It got solved by installing/updating to the latest version of loopback context: `npm install --save @loopback/context`